# How to optimize Firestore read/write operation

Tags: firebase, optimization, google-cloud-firestore

I try to make Stock monitoring app where users can make `Alert` when price change.

I have `Stock` document where I fetch from 3rd party API periodically.
Upon `Stock` update I fetch all `Alert` which meet condition and notify users with Firebase messaging.

Here is my models.

```
/stocks/{stockId}
id: String
price: Number

/alerts/{alertId}
stockId: String
price: Number
condition: [moreThan, lessThan]
uid: String // User who create alert

/users/{userId}
id: String
fcmToken: String
```

Every 5 minutes I fetch latest stock price and update stock document = `number of stock` write query.

```
function updateStockPrice(): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.WriteResult[]> {
  const db = admin.firestore();

  const options = {
    // Options for stock api
  };

  return client(options)
  .then(function(body) {
    let batch = db.batch()

    for(var stock in body){
      let data = // create data from json response
      let docRef = db.collection("stocks").doc(//id from 3rd party api)
      batch.set(docRef, data)
    }

    return batch.commit()
  });
}
```

On stock write update, loop through alerts and fetch fcm token from related user to send out push notifications = (`alert query` + `number of alerts matched condition for user query`) x `number of stock update`

```
export const onStocksUpdate = functions.firestore.document('stocks/{stockId}').onWrite(function(change, context) {

  const db = admin.firestore()

  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const previousValue = change.before.data();

  const stockId = Number(context.params.stockId)

  let p1 = db.collection("alerts")
      .where("stockId", "==", stockId)
      .where("condition", "==", "moreThan") 
      .where("price", "<=", newValue.lastPrice)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        const promises = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

          let data = doc.data()
          let user = db.collection("users").doc(data.uid).get()

          user.then(function(snapshot) {
            let userData = snapshot.data()

            return userData.fcmToken
          }).then(function(fcmToken) {
            const payload = {
              notification: {
                title: // title,
                body: // body
              },
              token: fcmToken
            }

            return admin.messaging().send(payload)
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
          })

          promises.push(user)
        })

        return Promise.all(promises)
      }).then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });

      return p1
})
```

Total write = `number of stock`
Total read = (`alert query` + `number of alerts matched condition for user query`) x `number of stock update`

Say I have 20 stocks, 1 user with 3 alerts.

Each 5 minutes I will use 20 write query and (1 + 3) x 20 = 80 read

In 1 day = 5760 write and 23,040 read

This seem too much operations for such a small examples. Is this the right way I should lay out data structure? Or is there a better way to do this?